# Get rid of format string conflict when using sympy

Tags: python, string, numpy, machine-learning, sympy

When I try to use sympy to find the derivative of the loss function, it raises a conflict with format string.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def predict(X, w, b):
    return np.dot(X, w) + b

def loss(X, w, b, Y):
    return np.mean((predict(X, w, b) - Y) ** 2)

X, Y = np.loadtxt("code/02_first/pizza.txt", unpack=True, skiprows=1)

# Convert X and Y to sympy symbols
X, w, b, Y = sp.symbols("X w b Y")

def gradient(X, w, b, Y):
    loss_expr = loss(X, w, b, Y)
    dw_dX = sp.diff(loss_expr, w)
    db_dX = sp.diff(loss_expr, b)
    return dw_dX, db_dX

def train(X, Y, iterations, lr):
    w = sp.symbols('w')
    b = sp.symbols('b')
    
    for i in range(iterations):
        loss_value = loss(X, w, b, Y)
        print(f"Iteration: {i:4d}, Loss: {loss_value:.10f}")
        dw_dX, db_dX = gradient(X, w, b, Y)
        w -= dw_dX * lr
        b -= db_dX * lr
    return w, b

w, b = train(X, Y, iterations=20000, lr=0.001)

print(f"\nw = {w:.10f}, b = {b:.10f}")
print(f"Prediction: x = 20 => y = {predict(20, w, b):.2f}")
```

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Pow.__format__
```

The data is here in txt (or via the [link here](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/pplearn/code/02_first/pizza.txt)):

```
Reservations  Pizzas
13            33
2             16
14            32
23            51
13            27
1             16
18            34
10            17
26            29
3             15
3             15
21            32
7             22
22            37
2             13
27            44
6             16
10            21
18            37
15            30
9             26
26            34
8             23
15            39
10            27
21            37
5             17
6             18
13            25
13            23
```

I can just use numpy but in doing so I need to calculate the loss function myself, which is not effective (and easy to raise error with brackets).

Why the error and why sympy is not compatible with format string? Also, how to generate a correct script with sympy?

Comment: At no point have you evaluated the symbols to numeric. You are passing symbols into the train. No train data passed in.

Comment: At no point did you initialize W or B

Comment: So how to use sympy while keeping numeric data as input?

Comment: I would advice against using `sympy` as the differentiation is not optimized with regards to matrices. Use numerical differentiation

Comment: is this all there is to the error message?  This is an unusual mix of numpy and sympy, so it's impossible run the code 'mentally'.  You need to test smaller pieces of code..

Comment: Without your data file we can't run the `loadtxt` line. Not that it matters since you throw that data away in the next line that defines symbols,  It doesn't convert anything.

Comment: I understand it's better to use sympy earlier like this: def loss (X, w, b, Y):
return sp.mean((predict (X, w, b) - Y))**2

But still I couldn't proceed and raised the same error.

I've edited the post and provided the code. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is - you can't use numeric formats, like `.10f` with `sympy expressions`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dirty sp code that will help you solve your problem. Note that you could optimize further, though the code is abot slow. Takes almost 10s for it to run 300 iterations. Again Consider using **numerical differentiation** instead.

```
def train(X, Y, iterations = 30, lr = 0.01):
    if len(X.shape) < 2:
            X.shape = (X.shape[0], 1)
            
    # variable containing the values
    n, p = X.shape
    _w = sp.randMatrix(p,1)
    _X = sp.Matrix(X)
    _Y = sp.Matrix(Y.ravel()[:,None])
    _b = sp.zeros(n, 1)
    I = sp.ones(n, 1)
    lr = lr / n
    
    # symbolic variables
    X = sp.MatrixSymbol('X', n, p)
    Y = sp.MatrixSymbol('Y', n, 1)
    w = sp.MatrixSymbol('w', p, 1)
    b = sp.MatrixSymbol('b', n, 1)
    
    # symbolic gradient 
    loss_expr = (X @ w + b - Y).T @ (X @ w + b - Y)
    dw_dX = sp.diff(loss_expr, w)
    db_dX = sp.diff(loss_expr, b)
    
    for i in range(iterations):
        vals = (X, _X), (Y, _Y), (w, _w), (b, _b)
        _w -= dw_dX.subs(vals).expand() * lr
        _b -= I @ I.T @ (db_dX.subs(vals).expand() * lr)
    return _w, _b[0] 

train(X,Y,3000,lr = 0.004)
(Matrix([[1.08256242352506]]), 13.1475574175438)
```

compare with:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
model.coef_, model.intercept_
(array([1.08111196]), 13.17258187357198)
```

Increase the number of iterations

Answer (score 0):

The actual error, when running the code (without the useless `loadtxt` line) is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[52], line 33
     30         b -= db_dX * lr
     31     return w, b
---> 33 w, b = train(X, Y, iterations=20000, lr=0.001)
     35 print(f"\nw = {w:.10f}, b = {b:.10f}")
     36 print(f"Prediction: x = 20 => y = {predict(20, w, b):.2f}")

Cell In[52], line 27, in train(X, Y, iterations, lr)
     25 for i in range(iterations):
     26     loss_value = loss(X, w, b, Y)
---> 27     print(f"Iteration: {i:4d}, Loss: {loss_value:.10f}")
     28     dw_dX, db_dX = gradient(X, w, b, Y)
     29     w -= dw_dX * lr

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py:394, in Expr.__format__(self, format_spec)
    392         if rounded.is_Float:
    393             return format(rounded, format_spec)
--> 394 return super().__format__(format_spec)

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Pow.__format__
```

It's the print line within `train` that's giving the problem.  From reading your question one might guess the problem was with the final print lines.  Full error message is important.

I don't know what `loss_value` is at this point, but since it complains about a `Pow`, let's try:

```
In [58]: i=1; loss_value=X**4;
In [59]: print(f"Iteration: {i:4d}, Loss: {loss_value:.10f}")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[59], line 1
----> 1 print(f"Iteration: {i:4d}, Loss: {loss_value:.10f}")

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py:394, in Expr.__format__(self, format_spec)
    392         if rounded.is_Float:
    393             return format(rounded, format_spec)
--> 394 return super().__format__(format_spec)

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Pow.__format__
```

But if I try the format without specifying the float format I get:

```
In [60]: print(f"Iteration: {i:4d}, Loss: {loss_value}")
Iteration:    1, Loss: X**4
```

A sympy expression cannot be formated as though it were a number!

You aren't seriously considering the distinction between sympy symbols and expressions and numbers, python or `numpy`.

Rerunning `train` without the problematic formats I get two iteration lines

```
Iteration: 0, Loss: (X*w - Y + b)**2
Iteration: 1, Loss: (-0.002*X*w + X*(-0.002*X*(X*w - Y + b) + w) - 0.998*Y + 0.998*b)**2
```

See how  `loss_value` is a `Pow` `sympy` expression, not a number.  If that doesn't make sense, you haven't read enough `sympy` documentation.

It then fails with a sympy ValueError:

```
     15 def gradient(X, w, b, Y):
     16     loss_expr = loss(X, w, b, Y)
---> 17     dw_dX = sp.diff(loss_expr, w)
     18     db_dX = sp.diff(loss_expr, b)
     19     return dw_dX, db_dX
....
ValueError: 
Can't calculate derivative wrt -0.002*X*(X*w - Y + b) + w.
```

I won't try to debug this.  Clearly you've written a bunch of code without doing any step by step testing/debugging.  And as the comments warn, mixing `sympy` and `numpy` seldom works.  At the very least you have to use `sp.lambdify` to convert sympy expression(s) to python functions.